# check given mobile number associated with whatsapp app or not in whatsapp

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

one of feature in my project invite contact function, i can  imported cantact invite button is thare that selected mobile number  check its whatsapp number or not incase that number in  whatsapp show whatsapp invite button or not in whatsapp number show sms invite button

```
_openWhatsApp(String mobilenumber) async {
    var url = 'https://wa.me/$mobilenumber/?text=$invitingText ${widget.basePath}';
    if(await canLaunchUrl(Uri.parse(url))){
      print("given number is whatsapp number");
      await launchUrl(Uri.parse(url));
    }else{
      print("number is not in whatsapp");
    }
  }
```

i want to check given is whatsapp number or not